# Rails 2.3.5 nested routes replace/delete route

Tags: ruby, namespaces, rake, routes

in Rails 2.3.5.  How can go from

```
rake routes
(in /home/railsApp)
tv_shows     GET    /tv_shows(.:format)    {:controller=>"tv_shows", :action=>"index"}  
             POST   /tv_shows(.:format)    {:controller=>"tv_shows", :action=>"create"}
new_tv_show  GET    /tv_shows/new(.:format)   {:controller=>"tv_shows", :action=>"new"}
edit_tv_show GET    /tv_shows/:id/edit(.:format) {:controller=>"tv_shows", :action=>"edit"}
tv_show GET    /tv_shows/:id(.:format)     {:controller=>"tv_shows", :action=>"show"}
PUT    /tv_shows/:id(.:format)             {:controller=>"tv_shows", :action=>"update"}
DELETE /tv_shows/:id(.:format)             {:controller=>"tv_shows", :action=>"destroy"}
```

to

```
rake routes
(in /home/railsApp)
tv_shows     GET    /tv/shows(.:format)    {:controller=>"tv/shows", :action=>"index"}  
             POST   /tv/shows(.:format)    {:controller=>"tv/shows", :action=>"create"}
new_tv_show  GET    /tv/shows/new(.:format)   {:controller=>"tv/shows", :action=>"new"}
edit_tv_show GET    /tv/shows/:id/edit(.:format) {:controller=>"tv/shows", :action=>"edit"}
tv_show GET    /tv/shows/:id(.:format)     {:controller=>"tv/shows", :action=>"show"}
PUT    /tv/shows/:id(.:format)             {:controller=>"tv/shows", :action=>"update"}
DELETE /tv/shows/:id(.:format)             {:controller=>"tv/shows", :action=>"destroy"}
```

route.rb

```
map.namespace :tv do |tv|
['shows', 'summaries'].each do |controller|
  tv.connect "#{controller}/:action",
    :controller => controller,
    :conditions => { :method => :get },
    :requirements => { :action => /auto_complete_for_\S+/ }
end

tv.resources :summaries
tv.resources :shows
```

end

In the DB the table is named tv_shows. But in my app i have folder tv with a file show in it.

```
App = ruby 1.8.6 and Rails 2.3.5
```

Can you point me to good nested route, namespace tutorial.

Comment: try this ['shows', 'summaries'].each do |controller|
  tv.connect "tv/#{controller}/:action",
    :controller => "tv/#{controller}",
    :conditions => { :method => :get },
    :requirements => { :action => /auto_complete_for_\S+/ }

Comment: if it works then ill add it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had

```
map.resources :tv_summaries  
map.resources :tv_shows
```

all the all up top in my route.rb file commenting those two line fixed the problem.